# beamer frame label option prevents longtable table to split and shows only the first frame of the longtable

Tags: beamer, longtable, labels

I am using `longtable` in `beamer`. I also need to `\ref` the frame where the `longtable` starts (to split on the successive frames). I used the `label={}` optional argument for the `frame` environment. Surprisingly, only the first slide of the table is shown now.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[label={reflabel},allowframebreaks]{Long long table}
        \begin{longtable}{c}
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a\\
        a           
        \end{longtable}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here only the first of the three slides (if shown correctly) of the longtable is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been fixed in the beamer dev version, thanks to @amonakov:

https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/52b35206589348124588696e6b710e092e2267ba

It should be included in beamer v3.72 or newer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Seems like beamer 3.69 is the recent version in texlive. But I went with the modified `beamerbaseframe.sty` in my project dir and then it works.

Comment: An up-to-date texlive has 3.71

Comment: okay reached that, but 3.71 is not 3.72 ;-)

Comment: @Arne Indeed, 3.72 isn't yet released :)